# Is it possible to setup a web server for asp and asp.net on linux?

Tags: asp.net, linux, asp-classic

I know it's MS's product,

but is it neccesary that it's hosted in windows environment?

More specificly,I need it to run in **Fedora**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) is what you are looking for.  It contains the ASP.Net runtime and development environment for Linux (and others).  You can't run classic ASP on it, but you most definitely can run ASP.Net.  That's probably what it is best at.

[Edited to clarify that you can't run ASP on Linux with Mono]

Comment: Just to clarify as this was the accepted answer - Mono relates to .NET, and therefore has no relationship with classic asp...

Comment: @Joe90 ,isn't classic asp also developped by MS?

Comment: Yes, it was MS's first attempt at a dynamic web page framework. But it is not ASP.NET...

Answer (score 4):

Consider looking at Mono.

Comment: Is Mono hosted in windows only?